# Can I use this sentence in a presentation?

Tags: usage, formal-language

When I start a presentation, can I say this

> Let me start with highlighting our achievement last month.

Is this sentence weird? If yes, is there any better?

Comment: **By highlighting..** NOT **with highlighting**!

Comment: Ronald is correct, but you also have to use "achievements" rather than "achievement" if you modify the sentence in the way he is suggesting: "Let me start **by highlighting** our **achievements** last month."   You could also say "Let me start with some highlights of our achievements last month."

Comment: @BadZen Good point.  In the case you have worked toward and accomplished just one achievement it is better to say, *Let me start by highlighting last month's achievement*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL  People here are being kind because you are a new contributor. But just so you know, we are not supposed to be a proofreading forum. :)

Comment: Oh, that's true - if you really mean just one achievement, then either use what @EllieK said or add an intensifier or some other adjective:  "last month's **big** achievement".  I have no idea why it's awkward as written in OP, but it is.